# Meta Slider Image Title

Tags: wordpress, slideshow

I am working on my website and just created a blog post with a slideshow created with Meta Slider. However I can see the caption of the img showing below the img but I also want to see the image title. Is it possible to show the image title above the image with some CSS or something else ?

Comment: You have to fetch that title to display image name

Comment: How can I fetch the title ?

Comment: also share a sceenshot of what you want and some code which you have tried, so that your question will not be downvoted or closed

Comment: Already image has title when you Hover on it, So do you want to display below image ?

Comment: This is how it looks like right now - https://prnt.sc/kjqywy
This is the image caption showing on the bottom of the photo. I want to show the title of the photo on the top part of the image. I have not tried any code.